# When Google Earth launches, only black screen is appearing

Tags: google-earth, installation, ubuntu

I'm installing google earth on ubuntu 12.0.4 in a following way:

1. Downloaded 64 bit.
2. sudo dpkg -i google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
3. google-earth

But when Google Earth launches, only black screen is appearing. There is no globe of local earth.

Same happened with me on another machine, but when i re-installed it, it works fine.

Could it be a graphic card issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Earth version 7 does not work behind proxy hence installed 6.2.1 in the machine.The issue was of graphics driver. Proxy was not the issue as the google server was reachable and search and other functions were working.After reconfiguring the graphics driver and installing google-earth, it was giving  google-earth server not reachable error since the port on which the machine was connected was unmasked, hence changed the port and after exporting proxy, the google-earth was up and running.

Answer (score 0):

If 3D is not enabled, then enable it. If it's not, it might be a [DNS problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/83645). Try using the OpenDNS or Google servers and see if it works.